# How do you achieve the following with CSS - page width issue

Tags: css

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I want to have a blue banner ( 100% width ) at the top of a page.  At the same time I want the text (facebook, twitter etc.) to remain the fixed width of the rest of the page and aligned to the right?

http://www.potentia.co.nz/

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R8c5s/4/) should work for you:

**HTML**

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="overlay">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#background
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    height:60px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

#overlay
{
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions:

1. Background image on the `body`. That's what they've done. It's not at all how I like to do it.
2. Make the header bar full width and use the standard "container + `width` + `margin: 0 auto`" technique, adding to it `text-align: right`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have two divs.  The parent `div` would have a width of 100%, and the child `div` would have the width of the content of the page (say, 1024px).  Just set the child `div` to be centered in the parent `div`.

Set the parent `div` to have the background of that blue, and the child to inherit that (or have a transparent background).

Answer (score 0):

This is something you are looking for.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/mJN8K/embedded/result/)

### HTML

```
<header role="banner">
    The Banner
</header>
<div id="content">
    <p>Dear proofread the assisted intuitively well before less behind far sank so and excepting irrationally where guinea crane goodness the bit elephant this improper inoffensive jeepers loyally circa iguana well spat impudently where outran blandly.</p>
    <p>Angelfish horse one numbly some before saliently dog less less the dishonestly glanced and at yikes belched this hence much where perceptible flashily burst thought rethought this hence in.</p>
    <p>Fishily oriole flipped swankily fired this genial jeez and peculiar far unaccountable yellow ouch upon this owing through a yikes this cast lazily hit yikes well much beneath rewound gnu.</p>
    <p>Fumed regardless jubilant much spelled this one overheard far in boomed buffalo snugly much wow firm darn titillating jeepers wryly that this that close oh one much supreme morbidly eagle as teasingly rabbit hilarious up.</p>
    <p>As lemur sped tough hedgehog wherever indignantly inconsiderately much goodness skillfully devilishly pushed that smirked in far this hello charmingly amid oh earthworm.</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
header[role="banner"] {
    width: 100%;
    font: 1.5em/1em sans-serif;
    background: #ff0450;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#content {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```